# Objecto JSON como value de Select - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-2.0

**Objecto**

```
export class Car {
  ID: String;
  dors: [{
    number: Number,
    postion: {
        x: String,
        y: String,
        z: String,
    }
  }]

}
```

Es posible definir el `value` de un `select` como un objeto y no un simple `string`. No me refiero al objecto a mostrar sino al `value`. He intentado usar `value={{}}` pero parece que sólo funciona con `string`. He intentado hacerlo con `ngValue`, pero parece no cambiar el comportamiento. Es posible hacerlo?

Quiero `car.dors.position` como `value`

**He intentado:**

```
<select *ngIf="car" class="form-control" #oneDoor  (change)="getRecDet(oneDoor.value);"  required >
   <option *ngFor="let oneDoor of car.doors" [ngValue]="oneDoor">{{oneDoor.position}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: el elemento `select` no tiene `value` como tal lo tienen los `option` que van dentro

Comment: Como dice el compañero, `value` es de `option` y `[ngValue]` (también en `option`) es lo que buscas, ya que mencionas que no te funciono, ¿podrías subir el template en donde lo utilizas?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo de la siguiente forma, agrega el `ngModel`.

```
    <select *ngIf="car" class="form-control" 
            [(ngModel)]="selectedDoor" #selectDoor 
            (change)="getRecDet(selectDoor.value);"  required >
          <option *ngFor="let oneDoor of car.doors" 
                  [ngValue]="oneDoor">
                 {{oneDoor.position}}
          </option>
    </select>
```

`selectedDoor` es un Objeto del tipo Door, dado que **la opción por "default"** (preseleccionada), puede ser un objeto sin valor, pero d**ebe ser del mismo tipo que el Value**.

> `[value]="..."` ->Solo soporta Strings.
>
> `[ngValue]="..."` -> Soporta cualquier Objeto - Necesita de un `ngModel`

**Recuerda:** agregar a tu Modulo `import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';`